# acessing itunes dj related information through the itunes api

Tags: c#, wpf, itunes, com-interop, itunes-sdk

i am in the process of writing a wpf application for a local bar

they currently are using itunes dj to manage a voting system to handle patrons song requests 
they are currently looking for a way to display this on a large hd screen above the bar the current version i have implemented shows basic itunes track information such as the current track playing with artist name, song name and album art    they would like to add the ability to display  the last 3 songs played in itunes dj the current top votes for upcoming songs and the next  5 upcoming tracks to help reduce the number of repeat songs which i plan on adding management routines for so the same song can only play once an hour

is there a way to access this type of information through the standard itunes com api for windows or is this something limited to applescript (i have seen applescript that can retrieve next 10 songs)

i have searched SO and google for similar topics but have so far come up with nothing on accessing itunes dj through the com api and very few article on doing it with applescript

Comment: ok i have figured out that i can simply pull itunes dj from the playlists collection  just need to figure out how to access the voting api

Answer (score 0):

Apple published their iTunes COM Interface **[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html)**. If you can access the iTunes DJ interface through the COM API, it'll be documented there.

Comment: Update 2018: this now redirects to their developer home page.